# Spring MVC url doesn't change on redirect

Tags: spring-mvc, url, redirect

Am using Spring MVC and tiles 2. I am trying to integrate Authorize.net payment gateway. When Payment transaction is successful Authorize.net sends the control to our server by posting(request method- POST as well ) it to our controller using server side forward. The URL it posts is

```
  http://example.com/cart/storeAuthorizedDotNetResponse
```

As this is a server side forward url doesn't change.
In method which accepts this response from authorize.net and which is mapped to above URL does some processing and checking and redirects the control to another method in same controller. This URL is

```
        http://example.com/cart/showOrderReceipt
```

and we redirect it using following :

```
           "redirect:/cart/showOrderReceipt"
```

at the end of the method. Now method mapped for /cart/showOrderReceipt gets called fine. However the browser URL doesn't change. It still remains

```
      https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
```

and this URL is the one from which we get forwarded POST request.

Any idea what is causing Spring MVC or( don't know what) not to change the URL.

Comment: If the URL is `http://example.com/cart/storeAuthorizedDotNetResponse` in the browser address bar, then the post to `http://example.com/cart/storeAuthorizedDotNetResponse` doesn't come from the browser, or it comes as an AJAX request.

Comment: http://example.com/cart/storeAuthorizedDotNetResponse URL is called by authorize .net people. May be not through browser. but its definitely not an ajax request. I will explain step by step may be                                                          1) we are on http://example.com/cart/viewCart 2) we checkout and  post the form to https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll so URL changes to https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll. 3) once transacton is compelete Authorize.net POSTs to our URL http://example.com/cart/storeAuthorizedDotNetResponse

Comment: 4)now method mapped to http://example.com/cart/storeAuthorizedDotNetResponse  redirects to another URL http://example.com/cart/showOrderReceipt at this point URL in browser is still https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll even though redirect works fine.

Comment: If the POST request comes from authorize.net, the redirect response will also go to authorize.net. The browser isn't aware of the traffic between authorize.net and example.com. There's no way the browser redirects when you send a response to authorize.net's server.

Comment: ok. so if the redirect is going to authrize.net server then how come the the method mapped in our controller is being called ? because we are redirecting to our own url? how does control comes back from authorize.net server when we redirect?

Comment: Probably because authorize.net follows the redirect like a browser would do. Doesn't authorize.net provide explanation on hos this process is supposed to work?

Comment: ya just going through their docs. they are saying they "relay" the response back to merchant's web server intead of redirecting it. Not sure what this means. I know it would be too much to ask you to do this but if you dont mind can you confirm it means the same thing as you are saying in the last comment, here is the link :https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536

Comment: I don't know enough of authorize.net to help you on this, sorry.